# how to get request by paasing an id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to get an element from the database by paasing the id of that element in the request. I have a controller file where i defined this function

```
import ReportsDAO from "../dao/reportsDAO.js"

export default class ReportsController {
static async apiGetReportById(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const reportId = req.query.id
      console.log(reportId)
      const report = await ReportsDAO.getReportByID(reportId)
      if (!report) {
        res.status(404).json({ error: "Not found" })
        return
      }
      res.json(report)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`api, ${e}`)
      res.status(500).json({ error: e })
    }
  }
}
```

and a DAO file where i defined this function

```
import mongodb from "mongodb"
const ObjectId = mongodb.ObjectID
let reports

export default class ReportsDAO {
  // data access objects for other crud methods
  static async injectDB(conn) {
    if (reports) {
      return
    }
    try {
      // will create it auto if dosen't exits
      reports = await conn.db(process.env.RESTREVIEWS_NS).collection("reports")
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(`Unable to establish collection handles in userDAO: ${e}`)
    }
  }
  static async getReportByID(reportId) {
    try {
      const getOneSingleReport = await reports.get ({
        _id: ObjectId(reportId),
      })

      return getOneSingleReport
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(`Something went wrong in getRestaurantByID: ${e}`)
      throw e
    }
  }
}
```

I get this error

Something went wrong in getRestaurantByID: TypeError: reports.get is not a function
api, TypeError: reports.get is not a function

Any why get is not a fucntion?

Comment: What is `reports`?

Comment: I hope it's clear now. I updated the code

Comment: You should review the query syntax mongodb. In DAO try : reports.find ({_id: ObjectId(reportId),})

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation of mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-collection/), there is no method for `get` in collection. You may use `find`.

Also, you may just change the `reports` to static property of the class for better encapsulation.

```js
import mongodb from "mongodb";
const ObjectId = mongodb.ObjectID;

export default class ReportsDAO {
    static reports;
    // data access objects for other crud methods
    static async injectDB(conn) {
        if (this.reports) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            // will create it auto if dosen't exits
            this.reports = await conn
                .db(process.env.RESTREVIEWS_NS)
                .collection("reports");
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(
                `Unable to establish collection handles in userDAO: ${e}`
            );
        }
    }

    static async getReportByID(reportId) {
        try {
            const getOneSingleReport = await this.reports.find({
                _id: ObjectId(reportId),
            });

            return getOneSingleReport;
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(`Something went wrong in getRestaurantByID: ${e}`);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```